# Why post value for checkbox is 'on'?

Tags: html, post, checkbox

The [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT) says:
`Value attribute is optional except when the type attribute has the value "radio" or "checkbox".`

But when I have `<input type='checkbox'>` with no value the browser sends 'on' value instead.

Is there any document or standard what value the browser should encode into into POST data when the 'value' attribute for checkbox is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML 4 terms, since you omitted the value attribute (which the section of the specification you quoted says is invalid HTML) you are encountering an attempt by the browser to recover from your error.

[HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#common-input-element-apis) codifies this behaviour.

> On getting, if the element has a value attribute, it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, it must return the string "on". On setting, it must set the element's value attribute to the new value.

Comment: What is the difference 'default' VS 'default/on'?

Comment: the 'default/on' mode is applied for 'checkbox/radiobutton': https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#input-type-attr-summary

Comment: @EugenKonkov — "Default" defaults to an empty string instead of on.